# Apply ngClass to select box

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am new to angularjs and i am trying to use ng-class. I want the default option in a select box to be gray and once an option is selected, for it to be black:

```
 <select data-ng-class="{true: black, false: gray}">
 <option data-ng-model="gray">Please Select Option</option>
 <option data-ng-model="black"> Option 1</option>
 <option data-ng-model="black"> Option 2</option>
 <option data-ng-model="black"> Option 3</option>
            </select>
```

CSS:

```
      .false
            {
                color: gray;
            }

            .true
            {
                color: black;
            }
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/d9WP5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an updated fiddle with a working result: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/4778/

The primary difference is that I used `ng-change` to call a function every time the selection changes, so that the class states can be updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-change to detect and call a function if there are any changes in the dropdown and change the class accordingly